# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: `"_puts"`

Tags: c, ld

I am writing a simple "Hello world" program using MacBook Air 2020 (M1) and the C code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
        printf("Hello world!\n");
        return 0;
}
```

clang version is

```c
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.201)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

However after I compiled it and try to run `ld hello.o -o hello` it gives the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_puts", referenced from:
      _main in hello.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Why is the symbol not defined?

Comment: Just an FYI in case your confused, the compiler has automatically optimized your call to printf on a plain string into a puts, for efficiency.

Comment: @PeteFordham To prevent that could I do: `(volatile int (*)(const char *restrict, ...)){printf}("Hello world!\n");` or something?

Comment: or just compile with -O0 if not you a crazy person

Comment: @PeteFordham — compiling with `-O0` is rarely a good idea.  Turning off all optimizations in a bigger program than the one shown would not usually be a good idea.

Comment: @PeteFordham What no, optimizations are good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link using the compiler (`clang hello.o -o hello`) — it will add the standard C library and the startup code, etc to the `ld` command line.

Add `-v` to the options to see what the compiler actually executes.

On an Intel Mac running macOS Big Sur 11.7, part of the information produced was this humungous long line which invokes the loader (`ld`) in a ridiculously obscure location:

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 11.0.0 12.1 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o tm59 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/sj/_v4_1hp947d_6qg_m75syr000000gn/T/tm59-7bf6b1.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```